# How am I supposed to initialize pthread mutexes?

Tags: c, initialization, pthreads, mutex

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t* mut;

int main()
{
        mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
}
```

The above code spits out `error: expected expression before ‘{’ token`.

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t* mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{

}
```

The above code spits out warning: braces around scalar initializer

So how am I supposed to initialize a mutex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a type error, you should use: `pthread_mutex_t` instead of `pthread_mutex_t*`:

```
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

The reason why compiler complains is that is tries to assign this macro expansion of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` to a **pointer**:

```
{ { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, __PTHREAD_SPINS, { 0, 0 } } }
```

With the corrected approach, you may pass `&mut` everywhere you need `pthread_mutex_t*`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should declare it as `pthread_mutex_t` and not as a pointer `pthread_mutex_t *`. You should also decide if the mutex is global or local to a function.

If it's global you can initialize it using: `pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

If it's local you have to call : `pthread_mutex_init(&mut,NULL);` (you have to check returned value)

Note that `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is a macro and you can't assign it to a pointer.

From `pthread_mutex_init()` man page :

> Only mutex itself may be used for performing synchronization. The
>   result of referring to copies of mutex in calls to
>   pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_trylock(), pthread_mutex_unlock(),
>   and pthread_mutex_destroy() is undefined.
>   Attempting to initialize an already initialized mutex results in
>   undefined behavior.

Usually the method with the function call is used if you want to set attributes to the lock (second argument of the function) such as shareable between processes or recursive.

Comment: Why no `=` sign in `pthread_mutex_t mut PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: Because I just forgot it.